# How to use radio button in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my asp.net MVC project I'm using radio button in order to send the id of the selected employee to controller.The problem is that the id received in the action is null.this is part of my code:

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<PFEApplication.Models.agent>
<div id="Leader">

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddNewLeader", "Equipe", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions {
                    UpdateTargetId = "Leader",
                    HttpMethod = "Post",
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
                    }))
    {
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
       @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.ID_agent)
       @Html.RadioButtonFor(modelItem => item.SelectedAgent, item.ID_agent)

       <img src="@Url.Content(@item.image_agent)" height="25px" width="25px" /> 
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nom_agent) 
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.prenom_agent)           
        <br />           

    }
    <br />
   <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    } 
    </div>
```

controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddNewLeader(agent ag)   
    {             
                [...] 
                agent agentRemplace = db.agents.Single(a => a.ID_agent ==   
                ag.SelectedAgent);                     
                db.SaveChanges();          
                return PartialView("exitAddNewLeader");
    }
```

Any help please.

Comment: Try renaming ag to agent in your actionresult.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your View, it seems that your AddNewLeader action method expecting collection of agents, but you are just passing a single agent object.
It does not make sense.
you should add a bind and ViewModel to post the collection of
[Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/nmarun/archive/2010/03/13/asp-net-mvc-2-model-binding-for-a-collection.aspx) is the example how to bind collection to the view and then posting these collections to controller.